# msvc and gcc different behavior

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
const T unit{ 1 };

template<typename T>
struct data
{
    typename T::value_type val;
};

struct decimal_def
{
    using  value_type = int;
    static const value_type unit_val() {
        return 10;
    }
};

template<typename T>
const data<T> unit<data<T>> { T::unit_val() };

auto decimal_data_unit = unit<data<decimal_def>>;

int main(){
    std::cout << decimal_data_unit.val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

exoect: 10
gcc: 10
msvc: 0

I think the reason of the difference between gcc and msvc is that compilers optimize `unit_val()` differently.

Comment: `decimal_data_unit` seems to be initialised before `unit<data<decimal_def>>`

Comment: No issues when turning into `constexpr` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9sxdf6)...

Comment: Funny - I get 10 with MSVC (Visual Studio 2019) and 0 with clang-cl. Looks like an issue with static/global constructor order. I think there may be a duplicate ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic initialization of **templated** non-local variables is [always unordered](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables), even relative to other variables defined in the same translation unit (in part because templated variables *might* also be defined in other translation units).  In this simple case, you can avoid the issue by using **constant** initialization instead: add `constexpr` to `decimal_def::unit_val` to enable that, and to the variable template definitions for clarity.